# Is $\varphi:x \mapsto A\cdot x$ an orthogonal projection for M

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I got the transformation
$\varphi:x \mapsto A\cdot x$
and the matrix 
$M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

I have to check whether $\varphi$ is the orthogonal projection for $M$.

To check if it is a projection, I check if the Eigenvalues of $M$ are either $0$ or $1$.

I calculated the Eigenvalues and the corresponding Eigenvectors:

$\lambda_1 = 1, \enspace v_1= \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},$

$\lambda_2 = 0, \enspace v_2= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},$

So it is a projection. But how do I check whether it is an orthogonal projection?

I received the hint to look for the Eigenvectors and the dot-product, but I don't get the connection. Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: What definition of orthogonal projection are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If this linear map is really an orthogonal projection onto the line spanned by $(-1,1)$, then it should map vectors *orthogonal* to $(-1,1)$ to $0$. That is, the $0$-eigenspace should be spanned by a vector orthogonal to $(-1,1)$. Is your vector $v_2$ orthogonal to $v_1$?

You may not yet know about the spectral theorem, but if the matrix were representing an orthogonal projection, it would have to satisfy $A^2=A$ and $A=A^T$. Your matrix is not symmetric.